# 6V to 220V relay switch

Tags: relay, switching

I want to control the coil of a relay using 6V input to turn on a relay which will activate a 220V device. Is there a relay that works for this application?

Comment: There certainly exists 220 V relays with 5 V coils. Check the datasheet for them and find out which would cope with 6 V.

Comment: There are plenty of relays with 6V coils. Why not use one of those?

Comment: Yes, there are many many such relays.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data sheets for 5V relays. Many will handle slightly higher voltages on the coil.

5V relays capable of switching 220V are very common.